# Getting the "phase" in a streaming way?

Tags: signal-analysis, phase

The context is a supervised learning problem. I have a dataset with features X and a target y. Among that dataset there is the date of the day encoded as an integer starting at 1. I have around 10k instances by days. I have found out that encoding the time on a circle (creating $cos(2*\pi t / T), sin(2*\pi t / T))$ for  $T = 7$ or $30$ as supplementary variables work pretty well to predict the outcome y.

Now I have two problems : in the test set the time also starts at 1 , so there will be some unknown phase and the test set will come in a streaming way, that is instance by instance.

Are there any streaming algorithm that would help me to rapidly get the phase for a given period and allow me to realign the circle encoding ?

Comment: Can't you just try all possible phase offsets for a few periods and check which results are closest to the predicted values over the interval.

Comment: Thanks that's a good start actually.